# Уступительные союзы

Tags: грамматика

Объясните пожалуйста, что такое уступительные союзы? Как их определить? Не нашел точной формулировки...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Говоря об уступительных союзах, важно понимать, что **такое отношение уступки** в сложноподчиненном предложении, то есть для начала следует ответить **на условный вопрос: кто и  кому "уступает".**

Оказывается, **уступительные  значения включают 4 компонента: потенциальная причина, ожидаемое следствие, превосходная причина, реальное следствие.** Таким образом, потенциальная причина уступает место превосходной причине,  которая и приводит к реальному следствию.

Например: **Хотя мне было очень узко и неловко в новом платье, я скрыл это от всех** (Л.Н. Толстой). На первом месте потенциальная причина (неловко в новом платье), ожидаемое следствие (я говорю об этом окружающим), превосходная причина (платье мне нравится), реальное следствие (я скрываю, что  мне в нем неловко).

**Таким образом, мы имеем следствие, не соответствующее названной в первой части предложения причине** — это и есть отношения уступки.

Подробнее [тут](http://avtoreferat.seluk.ru/at-jazykoznanie/92234-1-semantika-ustupki.php).

А теперь о грамматике. СПП с придаточными уступки бывают союзного и относительного подтипа.

**Союзный подтип:** простой союз ХОТЯ, сложные союзы НЕСМОТРЯ НА ТО ЧТО, ВОПРЕКИ ТОМУ ЧТО, союз-частица ПУСТЬ, ПУСКАЙ, модальное слово ПРАВДА

**Относительный подтип**: союзные слова КАК НИ, СКОЛЬКО НИ, КУДА НИ и т.д.

Comment: *...реальная причина (я скрываю, что мне в нем неловко).* А не следствие это? (Не разобрался как следует, может, всё и правильно...)

Comment: Артем, я исправила неточность в ответе: не реальная причина, а реальное следствие.

Answer (score 1):

Школьная грамматика относит к этим союзам частицы: хотя, пусть, пускай, которым противополагаются в другом предложении союзы однако, но, а, да, зато, все-таки.

При помощи этих союзов достигается так называемое "противительное" сочинение предложений: "хотя при стаде том и множество собак, да сам пастух дурак" (Крылов). "Хоть лишних (денег) не бывает, зато нет лишних и затей" (Крылов). "Пусть говорят: поэзия — мечта... пусть нет для мореходцев дальных сирен опасных, нет дриад в лесах густых, в ручьях кристальных золотовласых нет наяд... Пусть так! но в полдень листьев шепот так полон тайны, шум ручья так сладкозвучен, моря ропот глубокомыслен..., что сердце внемлет во всем таинственный язык..." и т. д. (Майков).
С. Б—ч.

Энциклопедический словарь Ф.А. Брокгауза и И.А. Ефрона. — С.-Пб.: Брокгауз-Ефрон. 1890—1907.

Это достаточно точная формулировка  находится в широком доступе: https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/brokgauz_efron/105184/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5