# Почему уступительные отношения так называются?

Tags: названия, терминология

На одном из ресурсов  явно **уступительные** отношения (соотнесенные с *несмотря на*) назвали **противительными**, и это меня удивило, тем более что никто не возражал против такой классификации.

В Сети, конечно, есть пространные рассуждения, определяющие значение уступки. А  вот можно очень коротко сказать, какие у этих отношений есть  **общие и отличительные признаки**?

И если отношения все-таки уступительные, то почему они так названы? Другими словами, **«кто кому уступает место"?**

Comment: https://housecomputer.ru/science/teaching_aids/russian_language/russian_grammar/3043-3057.html#3043  Надеюсь, найдете ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, но там так много буковок, и стиль академический.  А мне  только пару предложений с готовым ответом, а? Чтобы и другим можно было просто объяснить, формулировка  для взаимного понимания, а не только для себя. Мне кажется, что любое сложное понятие человек может объяснить предельно просто, в двух словах. В противном же случае он сам до конца не понимает сути этого предмета. Но всё равно спасибо, прочитаю, если никто не поможет  (я уже много всего прочитала на эту тему).Но очень хочется, чтобы помогли. Честно говоря, хочу себя проверить, свое понимание или заблуждение.

Comment: Но если коротко: в СПП уступки может употребляться и союз но: Хотя ... но. В этом случае союз носит значение логического противопоставления. Ср.:Хоть мал, но умен первый компонент значения - (если мал, значит не умен), (либо мал, либо умен), а второй компонент - (мал и в то же время (вопреки ожидаемому) умен).

Comment: Нет, Серж, это немного не то.  Я ведь говорю в общем плане, даже не обсуждая конкретных союзов. Вы согласны, что противоречие  и  несоответствие есть в обоих темах (иначе бы их не стали смешивать), а различие в чем? И почему все-таки такое название - уступка. Вероятно,  в этом названии и должна быть заложена  отличительная идея.

Comment: @Sharon 1. Вы совершенно верно понимаете, что в АГ нет ответов на Ваши вопросы. 2. Совет: не надо начинать вопросы с "почему". Вот просто не надо. На такие вопросы есть единственный ответ "Потому, что так сложилось".

Comment: Но ведь должен быть какой-то смысл в названии, я думаю, что он там есть. К тому же вопрос имеет практическое значение. Если несоответствие  и противоречие есть   в обоих темах,  то пользователи не будут их различать, что они делают. Но ведь это же неправильно.

Comment: *Но ведь должен быть какой-то смысл в названии* - какой смысл в том, что кошку назвали кошкой?

Answer (score 2):

> На одном из ресурсов явно уступительные отношения (соотнесенные с
> несмотря на) назвали противительными, и это меня удивило, тем более
> что никто не возражал против такой классификации

Контекст бы. Но вообще-то тут явная каша в терминологии. "Противительных отношений" в СПП грамматика (в школьном по крайней мере понимании) не знает. Есть некоторое число противительных сочинительных ***союзов***, которые могут оказаться в начале главного при уступительной связи: "хотя и..., но". Чаше всего, впрочем, подобные конструкции классифицируют как единый уступительный союз. Это, пожалуй, единственное, что связывает условные конструкции с противительными. При этом союз "несмотря на" никаким образом к противительным не относится. Так что все ваше обсуждение - сплошное недоразумение.

> Другими словами, «кто кому уступает место"?

Вы же сами дали ответ на этот вопрос.
[Уступительные союзы](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434806)
Или забыли?!
Не могу сказать, что тот ваш ответ мне понравился, но как-то странно спрашивать о том,
о чем сами миру и поведали.

> «кто кому уступает место"?

Ну вопрос так явно не стоит. Возможно, вас устроит ответ на вопрос, какое значение вкладывается в слово "уступительный/ое" (союз, отношение, придаточное). Есть основание подозревать, что вы ориентируетесь на первое (в БТС) значение слова уступить, даже на одно из его подзначений (Освободить для кого-л. место, предоставив кому-л. в пользование), в то время как и другие подзначения первого значения, и второе значение в целом дают вполне адекватные терминологии формулировки.  А более всего подходит, на мой взгляд, четвертое значение. ***Не выдержать сравнения с кем-, чем-л. в каком-л. отношении; оказаться менее достойным по сравнению с кем-, чем-л.*** - то есть "уступительные" надо понимать так, что придаточная часть уступает главной в своем влиянии на результат.

Comment: @behemothus  Спасибо. Да, забыла, а когда это было-то!  В другой жизни! Человек даже физически за несколько лет полностью обновляется, а ментально - не знаю за сколько. Я, к примеру, могу "обновиться" даже за год, а может, и за месяц. К тому же там дан конспект научной  монографии, а сейчас мне для души нужно, своими словами. Все дело в том, что не всегда это уступительное значение явно прочитывается, не всегда присутствуют стандартные уступительные союзы, и вот тогда начинаются споры о том, есть ли оно там вообще.

Comment: @Sharon *кто кому уступает место* - подумал над вопросом. Я не могу ответить на этот вопрос, но добавлю два слова в свой ответ.

Comment: @Sharon (из комментария чуть выше): _Да, забыла, а когда это было-то! В другой жизни!_ === Да, в другой. Тогда Вас звали, если не ошибаюсь, Жасмин (Jasmin).

Comment: @behemothus, вы ошибаетесь. Прежде всего "противительные отношения" существуют; статьи научные пишут, даже диссертации по филологии с таким термином в названии. Более того, есть и термин "уступительно-противительные отношения", который также употребляется в филологии.

Comment: *ИгорьД* -  *"противительные отношения" существуют;* - в грамматике? И именно в теории СПП? ссылку - в студию.

Answer (score 1):

1. На вопрос, "почему так названы", ответить могу: этот термин пришел из риторики, из теории так называемых "периодов". Их в императорской России изучали в школе и даже сочинения требовали писать с выделением таких периодов, чему есть немало подтверждений в литературе:

> Нужно было написать три периода: причинный, уступительный и относительный; но я не понял, как профессор учил сделать это, а просто взял и стал говорить, как приходит весна… (А. И. Левитов, 1869)

Уступительным называют такое отношение причинно-следственной связи, при котором причина оказалась недостаточной. То есть она в этом смысле "уступила" основному событию, и не повлияла на него.

2. О соотношении с противительным. Чаще всего уступительные отношения выражаются при помощи противительных союзов, и таким образом образуют противительные отношения:

> Солнце вышло из-за туч, но теплее от этого не стало.

Но могут быть противительные отношения и без уступительных:

> Иван в воскресенье занялся спортом, а его сосед весь день пролежал на диване.

Comment: Спасибо, про историю интересно. А вот в вашем предложении о солнце разве нет уступительного значения. Если солнце вышло, можно было бы ожидать тепла, а его не прибавилось.  Разве это  не нарушение причинно-следственных связей?  А во втором предложении использован сопоставительный союз А, разве он здесь выражает какое-то противоречие? Если есть явные сопоставительные союзы, то все ясно. Но все дело в том,что союзные аналоги, а также наречия, модальные частицы тоже могут выражать уступку, вот там и приходится различать противительные и уступительные значения по неявным признакам.

Comment: @ИгорьД  *этот термин пришел из риторики, из теории так называемых "периодов"* - да с периодами там как раз все понятно. Хотелось бы уточнить, вы точно уверены, что термин пришел в общую лингвистику из российской риторики, а не наоборот? Я очень сомневаюсь, что *английские ученые* посещали российские "школы" (под коими вы разумеете, надо понимать, гимназии).

Comment: @Sharon. Да, про солнце я именно привел пример уступительно-противительного отношения. Предложение и уступительное, и противительное одновременно. Так и говорят "уступительно-противительные", см. например работы проф. Перфильевой из НГПУ. Что касается "а", то это, безусловно, противительный союз, так и у Розенталя, и у Лопатина.

Comment: @behemothus, я ни в коем случае не утверждал, что это из РУССКОЙ риторики. По-английски (если вам интересны именно англичане) уступительный период называют concessive period, а уступительные отношения - concessive clause. Источник, конечно, латинский: concessivus modus, concessiva species. На русский язык его перевели как "уступительный" - одно из значений слова "cоncessio" - "уступка".

Comment: @ИгорьД *Источник, конечно, латинский* - уже лучше. Но при чем тут тогда риторика?   *(если вам интересны именно англичане)* - мне интересны не англичане, а общая лингвистика. А с англичанами - все очень просто. Условные отношения  - concessive relation. Вот я вас и спросил, они, что, тоже русскую риторику переводили?!

Comment: Короче, здесь движок не любит длинных дискуссий, я понял, что это ваша позиция, а не недоразумение. Формулирую своё замечание. "Условные отношения" (concessive relation)  - термин общей лингвистики. С него и переводили. Что англичане, что русские, что китайцы. Риторика тут рядом не лежала. Не ставьте телегу впереди лошади.

Comment: @behemothus, простите, я перестал понимать вашу логику. Я же только что сказал, что термин переведен с латыни НА русский. Не наоборот! И в английском он тоже из латыни. И я вновь не понимаю, что такое "русская риторика". Нет никакой "русской риторики", так же как нет какой-то особой "русской химии" или "русской геометрии". И я никогда такого термина не использовал.

Comment: @behemothus А, вот теперь понял!  "Условные отношения" (concessive relations) - термин общей лингвистики. Верно. А в него он попал из общей риторики - "условный период" (conсеssive period).

Comment: Я уже все сформулировал. Логика в том, что вы риторику совершенно за уши притянули, просто для красного словца. *А в него он попал из общей риторики* - я вас с самого начала и спрашивал. Каким образом?! Ну нельзя ж так безответственно городить предположения.

Comment: (+) Напоследок. В семантике и в учении о культуре речи есть понятие ***периода*** - вот оно-то вполне могло быть позаимсовано из риторики, но оно, к вашему сожалению, совсем не коррелирует с понятием ***наклонения*** в грамматике.